# Printing cosmetic extras when turning a 3D rubix cube array into ASCII art

Tags: arrays, go, ascii

I have a 4D array that I'm using to create a rubix cube, the dimensions are depth, height, width, and face, each given a letter to determine what color that face should be. Here is an image for reference:

[image: rubix cube image]

At this point I'm using a function called draw cube where I manually went in and printed the x's and spaces along with, for example, 4 letter c's in the color cyan with a function that prints as many colored letters as I inputted. Like this:

```
    printspace(22)

    printface(4, cube[2][0][2][4])

    fmt.Println()

    printspace(15)

    printface(1, cube[2][0][1][4])

    printspace(1)

    printx(2)

    printface(10, cube[2][0][2][4])

    printx(2)

    fmt.Println()
```

My question is, is there a better way to do this? Or should I abandon ASCII altogether and learn how to make a proper GUI?

I thought about making the ASCII art a string and somehow editing it with the rotation matrices I used on the 4D array but I wasn't sure how to do that, or if there was a better way to go about this, thanks for your help.